# Enable speech recognition while video recording

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition

I'm trying to implement video recorder using speech recognition technique.
Am able to open camera and start recording using speech recognition, but when video recording started my speech recognition get stop and am not able to pass any command to stop recording. Is there any way to pass voice command to stop recording. Or is it possible to run speech recognizer while video recorder is running. Tell me if any library present. Thanks in advance.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), VoiceManagerImpl.VoiceManagerListener {

private val ALL = arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)

private val START = 100
private var voiceManager : VoiceManagerImpl? = null

private var myCamera: Camera? = null
private var myCameraSurfaceView: MyCameraSurfaceView? = null
private var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if (hasPermissions(ALL)) {

        voiceManager = VoiceManagerImpl(this)
        voiceManager?.setVoiceManagerListener(this)
        voiceManager?.listen(START)

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, ALL, 101)
    }
}

private fun hasPermissions(permissions: Array<String>): Boolean {
    for (permission in permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

override fun onResults(results: ArrayList<String>?, type: Int) {
    Log.i("TAG", "Data : " + results?.get(0))

    if (results?.get(0) == "open") {
        openCamera()
        voiceManager?.listen(START)
    } else if (results?.get(0) == "start") {
        startCamera()
        voiceManager?.listen(START)
    } else if (results?.get(0) == "stop") {
        mediaRecorder?.stop()  // stop the recording
        releaseMediaRecorder() // release the MediaRecorder object

        finish()
    } else {
        voiceManager?.listen(START)
    }
}

private fun startCamera() {
    releaseCamera()

    if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this@MainActivity,
            "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        finish()
    }

    mediaRecorder?.start()
}

override fun onSpeechCompleted(requestCode: Int) {

}

private fun openCamera() {
    myCamera = getCameraInstance()
    if (myCamera == null) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this@MainActivity,
            "Fail to get Camera",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    } else {
        myCameraSurfaceView = MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera!!)
        val myCameraPreview = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.videoview)
        myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView)
    }
}

private fun releaseCamera() {
    if (myCamera != null) {
        myCamera?.release()        // release the camera for other applications
        myCamera = null
    }
}

private fun prepareMediaRecorder(): Boolean {
    myCamera = getCameraInstance()
    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()

    myCamera?.unlock()
    mediaRecorder?.setCamera(myCamera)

    mediaRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER)
    mediaRecorder?.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA)

    mediaRecorder?.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P))

    mediaRecorder?.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4")
    mediaRecorder?.setMaxDuration(60000) // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder?.setMaxFileSize(5000000) // Set max file size 5M

    val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
    audioManager.isMicrophoneMute = false

    mediaRecorder?.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView?.holder?.surface)

    try {
        mediaRecorder?.prepare()
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        releaseMediaRecorder()
        return false
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        releaseMediaRecorder()
        return false
    }

    return true
}

private fun releaseMediaRecorder() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder?.reset()   // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder?.release() // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = null
        myCamera?.lock()           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private fun getCameraInstance(): Camera? {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    var c: Camera? = null
    try {
        c = Camera.open() // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Err : " , e)
    }

    return c // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    if (requestCode == 101 && hasPermissions(ALL)) {

        voiceManager = VoiceManagerImpl(this)
        voiceManager?.setVoiceManagerListener(this)
        voiceManager?.listen(START)

    } else {
        finish()
    }
}

inner class MyCameraSurfaceView(context: Context, private val mCamera: Camera) : SurfaceView(context),
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private val mHolder: SurfaceHolder = holder

    init {
        mHolder.addCallback(this)
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)
    }

    override fun surfaceChanged(
        holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, weight: Int,
        height: Int
    ) {
        if (mHolder.surface == null) {
            return
        }

        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview()
        } catch (e: Exception) { }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder)
            mCamera.startPreview()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }

    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder)
            mCamera.startPreview()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        }

    }

    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {}
}
```

[VoiceManagerImpl.java](https://github.com/LINKIT-Group/ping-pong/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nl/linkit/itnext/pingpong/managers/VoiceManagerImpl.java)

[VoiceManager.java](https://github.com/LINKIT-Group/ping-pong/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nl/linkit/itnext/pingpong/managers/VoiceManager.java)

Comment: Can you provide link to documentation for `VoiceManagerImpl`?

Comment: I had share all needed stuff.

Comment: Android normally only allows one audio recording client at any given time. So since your `MediaRecorder` is recording audio, the `SpeechRecognizer` probably can't run at the same time, unless there's some device where it somehow bypasses the normal audio recording chain.

Comment: I know that but any how can i pass the control of AudioManager from MediaRecorder to SpeechRecognizer. In this case it's ok if my video recording is without sound. @Michael

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: hello did you manage to find any workaround solution for this?